# How can I get metadata of cluster with ES 5.6 high level rest client?

Tags: elasticsearch, rest-client

I want to get the metadata of my ElasticSearch cluster which's version is 5.6.x. And I'm using the high level rest client.

I've checked all the api that rest client support, but didn't find the way to get metadata.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/5.6/java-rest-high-supported-apis.html

How can I get metadata of cluster with ES 5.6 high level rest client?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful but it might help you, but you can fetch some attributes using following, see if this is useful for you.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-admin-cluster.html